# Laravel - Store checkbox array as boolean in pivot table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, pivot-table

I have two Models **Shop** and  **Product** with Many-to-Many relationship. In the pivot table, **product_shop**, there are three columns as below, where I want to pair product_id value whether it is expired or not. (boolean 1 or 0).

Pivot relation works fine, but the Controller currently gets **is_expired** values as **on** instead of 1 or 0. I can check with normal value with `$request['is_expired']`, but how can I check with multiple (array) checkbox? Also, how can I pair `product_id` value with respective `is_expired` boolean value?

**This is the table relationship what I want**

```
shop_id | product_id | is_expired
   10   |    101     | 1
   10   |    201     | 0
   20   |    301     | 1
```

My **Shop Table**

```
  id  | shop_name | location
  10  | General   | USA
  20  | Special   | Canada
```

My **Product Table**

```
  id  |    product_name     | price
  101 |   Cream Biscuit     | 9
  201 |  Sugar-free Biscuit | 11
```

Model **Shop.php**

```
class Shop extends Model
 {  
   protected $fillable = [
    'shop_name', 'location'
   ];

   public function products()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('id', 'is_expired')->withTimestamps();
     }
 }
```

Model **Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
 {

  protected $fillable = [
    'product_name', 'price'
   ];


  public function shops()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class)->withPivot('id', 'is_expired')->withTimestamps();
    }
  }
```

View **create.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('product_store') }}" method="post">
 @csrf
 <!--For Shop-->
 <input type="text" name="shop_name">
 <input type="text" name="location">

 <!--For Products-->

 <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="101"><input type="checkbox" name="is_expired[101]"><label>Cream Biscuit</label>

 <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="201"><input type="checkbox" name="is_expired[201]"><label>Suger-free Biscuit</label>

  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Contoller **ShopController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 $product= $request['product_id'];
 $is_expired= $request['is_expired'];

 $shop = new Shop;
 $shop->shop_name = request('shop_name')
 $shop->location = request('location')

 $shop->save();
 $shop->products()->attach($product, array('is_expired' => $is_expired));
}
```